# how to stop components in android GUI not to overlap

Tags: android

I am trying to make the image button fix completely on the screen and the spinner. It seems to have a problem with the weight sum and weight layout. I have tried to fix it, but haven't gotten anywhere. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".ElderActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:background="#ffab7c74"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Smart House"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:autoText="true"
            android:textColor="#fffff7f4" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/environment"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/law"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/consumer"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/educations"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[screem shot of screen][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPFDi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice to use the weight option, especially if you have weight options in deep hierarchy of layout. For your example you need to use **RelativeLayout** or even **TableLayout**.

But if you want a mess up for your bottom part you can use tricky thing like:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <View android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/text2"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```